# Issue with jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the answer in a check box dynamically.

```
var multiQ= new Array();
var questionIndex = 0;
function updateQuestion(direction) {
    questionIndex += direction;
    if (questionIndex <multiQ.length && questionIndex >= 0) {
        $("#question").html(multiQ[questionIndex].question);
        $.each(multiQ[questionIndex].answers, function(key, val) {
            $('#answers').append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="key">' + val + '</label>');
        });
    }else {
        questionIndex -= direction;
    }
}  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {    
        function Question(q,correactA,array){
            this.question=q;
            this.correct_a=correactA;
            this.answers=array;    
        }    
        multiQ= new Array();
        for (i=0;i<5;i++){
            var q = json.questions[i].question;
            var corA= json.questions[i].correct_answer;
            var a = json.questions[i].answers;
            var aString = "";
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {aString += a[k] ;})
            multiQ[i]=new Question(q,corA,a);
        }
        updateQuestion(0); 
    });
});
```

The questions are displayed well dynamically, but I have a problem with the answers.
The new answers are added to the end of the former answers instead of replace them.
Which command should I use instead append?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `.html()` instead.

To achieve without jQuery use something like: `document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = 'txt'`

Comment: It turns out that I had to add `$('#answers').empty();` before 

    $.each(multiQ[questionIndex].answers, function(key, val) {
                $('#answers').append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="key">' + val + '</label>');
            });

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!